# jquery nested json parsing each looping

Tags: jquery, json

I have this responseText from an AJAX form submission:

```
"{"form_errors": {"first_name": ["Can only contain a-z, A-Z and -"]}, "messages": [{"message": "dur", "level": 40, "extra_tags": "danger"}]}"
```

I need to be able to loop through all form_errors such as:

```
            $.each(errors, function(index, value)
            {
                if (index !== "__all__")
                {
                    apply_form_field_error(index, value);
                }
            });
```

I have tried:
              var errors = JSON.parse(data.responseText['form_errors']);
to try and give myself something to loop through but am unable to access form_errors in a suitable manner to loop through.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse the whole string using

```
var response = JSON.parse(str)
```

then access using

```
response.form_errors
```

note that the current string is not properly escaped